# Is there any halachic problem with providing a service (e.g., matchmaking) to someone for free, when others pay for it?

Tags: halacha, money, transactions, shidduchim-dating

I recently got an interesting email from a shadchan (matchmaker), which I've paraphrased here:

> I have a potential match in mind for you. However, it is a halachic problem if I set you up with this person, since we have many members who pay to be part of our organization.

This person offers a subscription-based service (i.e., you pay on an annual basis to be a member of his/her "organization," which presumably earns  you the right to be set up by these shadchanim). The email went on to detail the various pricing plans available for this service, and encourage me to purchase their "VIP service."

The shadchan also said that I can just "donate" directly to the organization through a payment processor (instead of signing up for the subscription) and they'd be happy to work with me that way, too. So it appears the "halachic problem" is resolved by payment, not by membership in the organization.

Is there any conceivable basis for the claim that "it is a halachic problem if I set you up with this person, since we have many members who pay to be part of our organization"?

Comment: maybe she's being masig gevul against herself.

Comment: For those that are interested, this particular email also prompted me to ask [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/63893/your-friend-has-sent-you-a-message-on-our-website-register-to-see-it-is-the) on [ux.se]

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a scam?

Comment: The Shadchan may be prohibited _by the service_ to work as a Shadchan elsewhere (no-compete).

Comment: @DoubleAA is a non-compete halachically valid? Seems it's [not simple](http://www.businesshalacha.com/hotline-articles/competition)

Comment: @DoubleAA also, the shadchan is founder and president of the "organization," a non-compete seems unlikely

Comment: I don't think it's got anything to do with halachah. The shadchan wants you to pay.

Comment: @user3949142 I'm inclined to agree, but since the shadchan claimed a "halachic problem" I was wondering if anyone could come up with one that might apply

Comment: @ff524 Is it in the Shadchan's right to forgo the payment ? Imagine going to a restaurant where the server told you, I want to give you a free hamburger but I have a problem since most people pay for their meals. On the other hand telemarketers are often given leeway to offer a freebie to catch or maintain the customer. So the question really starts with what is this "Shadchan" authorized to do ?

Comment: @eramm the restaurant owner can give you a meal "on the house". If this Shadchan is the founder and president, that would seem to be analogous.

Comment: @Scimonster I did not speak about the owner of the restaurant rather a waiter. It is not clear from the original question if the Shadchan is in a position where she has the authority to make such a deal.

Comment: @eramm the OP in a comment says that they are the president.